# Android profile native thread?

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, profiling, native

I am working on optimize a native library with lots of legacy code.

The library creates some thread using pthread to do cpu/io work asynchronously.

I really want to do some profiling to find the bottleneck in the whole processing.

I try to use https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler follow the guide.

Include the profiler static library. Make my other jni project linked to the static library. add -pg flag:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS_ALL += -pg
```

use

```
monstartup("libAVCodec.so");

moncleanup()
```

When I get the gmon.prof and use the command tool to analyse it, I only get useless infomation, I call moncleanup after 10 seconds monstartup is called, but the result seems only has 0.01 seconds.

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name
 50.00      0.42     0.42                             Q_ABGRToYRow_C
 44.05      0.79     0.37                             Q_ABGRToUVRow_C
  1.19      0.80     0.01                             TMM::TMMLog::LogExtend(TMM::TMMLog::TPriority, char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)
  1.19      0.81     0.01                             std::__node_alloc_impl::_M_allocate(unsigned int&)
  1.19      0.82     0.01                             std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()
  1.19      0.83     0.01                             std::priv::_String_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_allocate_block(unsigned int)
  1.19      0.84     0.01                             std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::priv::__copy_integer_and_fill<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(char const*, int, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, int, int, char, char, char)
```

I open the gmon.perf using notepad++, looks it has error, but I don't know how to address

[image]

I will go for fplutil later.